# AJAX (Response Undefined)

Tags: javascript, ajax

Previously I was a beginner in using AJAX, in this case I retrieve data from 2 different endpoints, data for phone number and token data. Previously I have managed to get the data. but I want to use custPhone and custToken data in the sso function, but when I execute it, the variable returns an undifined value, while in the console.log the data appears. maybe someone can help to use this variable so it doesn't result in undefined

```
const button = document.getElementById('btn-submit');
button.addEventListener('click',function(){
  
  const email = document.getElementById('CustomerEmail').value; 
  
   function sso(url, custPhone, custToken, callback){
      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.open("POST", url);

      xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
      xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", `Bearer ${custToken}`);
      var data = `{
          "phone_number": ${custPhone},
          "countryCode": "ID",
          "programId": "4002203192624"
      }`;

      xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
         if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
            console.log(xhr.status);
            const value3 = JSON.parse(xhr.response);
            const SSO = value3.url; 
            callback(SSO);
         }};


      xhr.send(data);
  }
  
  
  function getPhoneNumber(url, callback){
    // GET CUST DETAIL BY EMAIL
    const email = document.getElementById('CustomerEmail').value;

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET", url);

    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    xhr.setRequestHeader("X-Shopify-Access-Token", "shppa_8key");

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
       if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
          const value1    = JSON.parse(xhr.response);
          const custPhone = value1.customers[0].phone;
          callback(custPhone);
       }};
  
    xhr.send();
  }
  
  
  
  function getTokenCust(url, callback){
      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    
      xhr.open("POST", url);
      xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
      xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic aWY5b0IwZHFZQTZzcHFpMGR3ajF0VnI3cTp2djhmRGJ5WTNVZHB6amtYSXd3dEZ2bVNUSkVKcE5scHp4VjJpUWxrbWt4VzJ3VTlzRg==");

      xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
         if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
            const value2 = JSON.parse(xhr.response);
            const custToken = value2.access_token;
            callback(custToken);
            
         }};

      var data = `{
        "username": "98080001",
        "password": "0001",
        "grant_type": "password",
        "scope": "offline_access"
      }`;

      xhr.send(data);
  }
  
  
  getPhoneNumber(`https://zone-group-store.myshopify.com/admin/api/2021-07/customers/search.json?query=email:${email}`, function(custPhone){
    getTokenCust('https://api.gift.id/v1/pos/token', function(custToken){
      sso('https://api.gift.id/v1/pos/sso/wallet', custPhone, custToken, function(sso){
          alert(sso);
      });
    });
  });
```

Comment: which variable is coming as undefined?

Comment: @VireshMathad custPhone & custToken Variable

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce it. Can you share test email that I can try?